# injecting provider parameter fails in AngularJS for npm package angular-credit-cards

Tags: angularjs

I've modified the plunkr example plnkr from the github repository https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-credit-cards .  The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to get the second parameter of the function (creditcards) to be anything but null.  I believe I'm using it correctly bus something is clearly wrong.

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YHbbluTtB1Fd2d3lChL8?p=preview

```
angular.module('ccDemoApp', ['credit-cards'])
  .controller('SettingsController2', ['$scope', SettingsController2]);

function SettingsController2($scope,creditcards) {
  if (creditcards){
    alert('creditcards defined');
  } else {
    alert('creditcards not defined. problem')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation either use the module or include the code then refer to the module name.  I don't see you including the code anywhere so credit-cards is null.

// node module exports the string 'angular-credit-cards' for convenience
angular.module('myApp', [
  require('angular-credit-cards')
]);
// otherwise, include the code first then the module name
angular.module('myApp', [
  'credit-cards'
]);

Comment: Hi @James, I'm fixing example now. I meant controller and not filter.

Comment: Here is the updated plunkr that uses the controller http://plnkr.co/edit/YHbbluTtB1Fd2d3lChL8?p=preview  I'm following what I think is the doc from the npm project and seems to me it should work

Comment: my real problem uses the controller. I'm trying to get the creditcards provider injected into the controller (filter was just what was in the original example I modified from the project)

Comment: that's it.  Thanks James for giving me the example. I can see it working and I'm sure I can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in declaration of controller. You're using an injection array and forget to include the dependency name as a string. It should be

```
.controller('SettingsController2', ['$scope', 'creditcards', SettingsController2]);
```

I discourage people from using such syntax as it tends to have errors like this and is not clear in reading. If you are already using minification you can always get use of [`ngAnnotate`](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)

Comment: Yeah I was trying to get him to that he wasn't getting it so I sent him over a plnkr